# What would happen if I use a USA (GMRS/FRS) two-way radio in Europe?

Tags: legality, europe, communication, radios

This question is the opposite from [this one](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5174/what-are-the-consequences-of-illegally-using-a-446-mhz-pmr-in-the-north-amer): What would the consequences of using a US two-way radio (GMRS/FRS) in Europe? I know Europe has their own frequency range for two-way radios (PMR), but for the moment let's remove buying new radios from the list.

Does anyone else use the same frequencies (does the radio channel matter)? Would I be able to hear official chatter?

If I were to broadcast, who (besides my intended receiver) would hear me, and would they come looking for me? Would I risk interfering with anything?

Comment: I think this will vary per country. As I understand it a country designates what channels can be used for what traffic (there is a finite amount of bandwidth) so it would depend if any of the GMRS frequencies interfere with other equipment. The outcome could vary from making your neighbours radio buzz to interfering with police communications. Typically you should stick to your countries designated Frequencies.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you happen to broadcast on a private or emergency frequency they'll simply say something along the lines of, "Keep this frequency clear."

Comment: I'm pretty sure the specific frequency allocation in that range (low UHF) is country-specific, and in many cases, frequencies are assigned by regulatory bodies to stations (even mobile stations) within a given geographical area, not the whole country. So for a proper answer to this, you would have to specify at least which country you are talking about, so that the specific country's frequency allocation plans can be consulted and referenced. Those are the only way to know how a given frequency range is used in a given country. Europe is not homogenous.

Comment: Good point @MichaelKjörling. I am in Switzerland, but my hope is this question (and hopefully its answer) would be useful to all Europeans.

Comment: I found the Swiss frequency allocation here: http://www.bakom.admin.ch/themen/frequenzen/00652/00653/index.html?lang=en

Answer (score 5):

Personal radio devices in Europe use a different frequency (446 Mhz). According to a quick google search the frequency range of GMRS/FRS (462-467 Mhz) is used by fire brigades in UK, police in Russia and licensed radio amateurs in Germany... blocking frequencies of police or fire brigades will certainly cause you trouble here.